# Gaussian posterior/posterior predictive mean

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, posterior

I'm a little confused regarding the difference between the posterior and the posterior predictive distribution. I know that the posterior is a distribution over the parameter, while the posterior predictive is a distribution over the data.

Am I correct in assuming that for a Gaussian prior and likelihood, the posterior mean will be equal to the mean of the posterior predictive distribution?

Comment: As you mentioned, the posterior distribution is a distribution over the parameters and the posterior predictive is over data. If you calculate the mean of the posterior distribution, then it will say something about the parameters. Likewise the posterior mean of the posterior predictive distribution will give you information about the data. These are not necessarily equal as they are providing information about different things.

If you have doubts on these concepts, I think you would greatly benefit from rereading again the definitions and reading examples.

Comment: Of course the statement is not true in general, but for Gaussians the parameter $μ$ directly corresponds to the mean of the distribution, that's why I thought that they should be equal in that specific case?